# How to check stream for failure in same line as initialization?

Tags: c++

Can I do this?

```
if (auto&& ifs = std::ifstream("main.cpp") && ifs)
{
    std::string word;
    ifs >> word;
    std::cout << word;
}
```

My error is `use of 'ifs' before deduction of 'auto'`. I want to avoid initializing and checking for error on separate line. My intent is to limit the scope of the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if you input was successful anyway so you are best off to do something like this:

```
std::string word;
if (std::ifstream("main.cpp") >> word) {
    std::cout << word;
}
```

If you need to use the stream object for other operations, you can use

```
if (std::ifstream ifs{"main.cpp"}) {
     // code as before with input checking added, of course
}
```

Comment: @user4613101: ah, yes: in C++11 stream operations work on rvalues which wasn't there prior to C++11, i.e., it used to be necessary but isn't any more.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of `&& ifs`. The value of the assignment expression is the value of `ifs` after assignment, which will be true if the open succeeded.

The error is because you're initializing `ifs` from the value `std::ifstream("main.cpp") && ifs`, which is circular; you can't expect to evaluate that expression because `ifs` isn't defined yet when the expression is evaluated.